# Can I disable keyboard input to a specific control?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

Is it possible to disable keyboard input to a control? For instance a `ListView`? How do I do that? I've tried overriding the `KeyUp` `KeyDown` events but apparently that was not the way?

`IsEnabled` is a good solution, however I only wish to disable keyboard interaction and leave mouse interaction intact.

Comment: So you just want to punish keyboard users?

Comment: Indeed - I do. I'm looking for mouse-only

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Handling the `KeyDown` event is too late, but you can handle the [PreviewKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown.aspx) event and that should give you the behavior you are looking for:

```
private void MyListBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Dear maciek, the only thig you need to do is using OnKeyDown event just do

```
private void txtInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            e.Handled = true; // user can input
            e.Handled = false; // user cannot input
    }
```

Comment: hey Maciek, youshouldn't use both of Handled code above, as I mentioned in comments you have to use on of those

Answer (score 2):

KeyDown generally works for me if you do the following in it:

```
e.Handled = true;
e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

A more complete example with a practical application (disabling input from non-numeric characters): http://cccontrols.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/34146#611536

John makes a good point though. Any reason you would want to disable interaction with the `Control` but not set `Enabled` = `false`?

**Edit:** I just noticed the WPF tag. Not so sure of my answer anymore since I'm a WPF hater ;-)

Comment: can't access e.SuppressKeyPress :/

Answer (score 1):

That is the purpose of the `WebControl.Enabled = false;` to prevent it from responding to user input.

edit: *now that the question has changed*, disabling the control is no longer a solution.  However I think a control that responds to mouse clicks by not keyboard is *buggy*, not everyone prefers to use the mouse.

Comment: I apply a minus point, cause this approach will disable the control,and that not the solution

Answer (score 0):

`KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` : Gets or sets a value indicating whether the KeyPress event was handled.

Property Value
`Boolean`
`true` if the event is handled; otherwise, `false`.

if you set `e.Handled = true`, keyboard event not dispatch anymore.