# How to "kill" pressed shift key?

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the application for "ok and other".

If I use this shortcut in case I have focus in some editing field, editor losed focus and that is in the menu of application (that causes pressed SHIFT).

How can I "kill" pressed SHIFT to keep the focus in the editor?

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift))
    {
        ???
    }               
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is in WPF something like "SuppressKeyPress" in WinForms?

Comment: may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230407/4610605) help you ?